# Adding button/menu in ionic 2 content page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am learning ionic 2 and as part of my learning process, i am creating a basic ionic 2 app.

Below is a page from my app. I have some text contents which i would like to display in `About` page in app. Initially only title must be visible and once the user clicks on the title, another page with text content must be opened.

How do i achieve this? I mean, which component to use for this? Any guidance will be great. Any other approach/suggestion to achieve this is also welcome, i want the page to be clutter free.

[image]
[image: Current page in app]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To navigate from one page to another, You would have to use the `navController` offered by Ionic 2. Basically all navigation in Ionic 2 happens using the **Stack** data structure abstracted through the `navController`. This way you can push pages on top of other pages using

```
.push(ClassNameOfThePageYouWantToPush,{paramsYouWantToPassToTheNewPage})
```

And existing pages can be popped from the stack by calling

```
.pop(ClassNameOfThePageYouWantToPush,{paramsYouWantToPassToTheNewPage})
```

You can find more info [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/)

To trigger it in the UI, use a (click) handler to call a function

```
<ion-title (click)="openNextPage()">About</ion-title>
```

In you `.ts` file you can then import the navController and add it to the constructor.

```
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-page2',
  templateUrl: 'page2.html'
  })
export class Page2 {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }

  openNextPage(){
    this.navCtrl.push(PageYouWantToOpen);
  }
}
```

Because this is such a common feature when you use the ionic 2 cli to generate a page

```
$: ionic g page my-page
```

It will automatically add the navController and navParams ready to be used.

Comment: How to display that in UI? I mean, how to trigger push or pop?

Comment: check Edited answer

Comment: Just wanted to add: inject `NavController` in your constructor like so `constructor(public navController: NavController) { ... }` else you can't use it. (Don't forget the `import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';` Also see the documentation about this component: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/